# jQuery Check if th from data table contains a button and skip tr

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have a data table into html page and i want to get values from tfoot but i have sometimes input button. So, i thank check if the `th` from tfoot table contains input button and then skip the `tr`, not to get the values. My jQuery code does not work because i think, there is a button in each row (`tr`).

My data table :

```
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Total</th>
        <th>20 420</th>
        <th>17 306</th>
        <th>3 114</th>
        <th>15.25</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th align="left" colspan="10">
            With :
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-small"><i class=" icon-signal"></i> graph</button>
        </th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

My jquery code :

```
// Get table footer data
$("#myTable tfoot tr").map(function() {
    footer = [];
    if($(this).find('input[type="button"]').length != 0){
        $(this).find('th').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().trim();
            if(text != "") footer.push(text);
        });
        footers.push(footer);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you looked into using the has() method

http://api.jquery.com/has/

usage would be like:

```
var hasButton = $("th").has("button").length ? true : false;
```

**UPDATE**:

add this above your map() method it will add a class to the TR that has a child of button:

```
$(".btn-small").parents("tr").addClass("has-button");
```

then you in your map method you will check if the TR does not have that **.has-button** class

```
// add .has-button class to all TR parents of the .btn-small button
$(".btn-small").parents("tr").addClass("has-button");

// use map() to selct #myTable tfoot tr that dont have has-button class
$("#myTable tfoot tr").not(".has-button").map(function() {
    footer = [];
    if($(this).find('input[type="button"]').length != 0){
        $(this).find('th').each(function() {
            var text = $(this).text().trim();
            if(text != "") footer.push(text);
        });
        footers.push(footer);
    }
});
```

notice how i used the **not()** method to exclude TR that have that class $("#myTable tfoot tr").not(".has-button")

http://api.jquery.com/not/

to get the last class in the attribute class try this:

```
var lastClass = $('#myTable tfoot tr button').attr('class').split(' ').pop();
```

**pop** will get the last item in the array

does that help?

Comment: Yes, but how i can skip the `tr` into my loop and not get this row?

Comment: Yes it works but i have a problem because my class to button is variable (for example : ".btn btn-small XXX YYY") and there are multiple classes. How i can get the last class ?

Comment: to get the last class try .. var lastClass = $('#myTable tfoot tr button').attr('class').split(' ').pop();